# SCRAPY: Writing XLSX file from PANDAS in Scrapy

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm new to scrapy and want to write data in excel. I knew the way I'm writing the dataframe. I will be able to get the data from only one page. But I'm confused, where I have to define the dataframe to write all the data in excel.

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import pandas as pd


class MonarkSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'monark'    
    allowed_domains = ['monark.com.pk']
    start_urls = ['https://monark.com.pk/collections/t-shirts']

    #Extracting links   
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//h4[@class="h6 m-0 ff-main"]/a')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)


    def parse_item(self, response):
    
        item = {

            'Product_Name' : response.xpath('//h1[@class="h3 m-0"]/text()').get(),
            'Price' : response.xpath('//span[@class="price price--sale"]/span[2]/text()').get(),
            'Description' : response.xpath('//div[@class="tabs__content rte overflow-hidden"]/p/text()').get()
           }
       # writing data  
       df = pd.DataFrame([item],columns=['Product_Name','Price','Description'])
       df.to_excel('Monark.xlsx',sheet_name='Monark_DATA', index=False, header=True)
```

[Excel Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50VI9.png)

Comment: there are many ways, one can be, your parse_item return a dictionary or list, which you can keep on accumulating. And once all is collected, then create a dataframe and then write to excel. So the creation of df and df.to_excel, can be be outside the class. So in class build the list and then at end build df and write.

Comment: By far the easiest thing to do here would be to export your data to CSV using the built in capabilities e.g. `scrapy crawl monark -o data.csv` Excel can open these files or you can convert them to excel with `pandas` after scraping. Is there a particular reason this wouldn't work for you?